# How to access an element in the Template of a WPF GroupItem

Tags: c#, wpf, controltemplate, expander

I have a `ListView` which is filled with some items. These items have two properties, `ItemName` and `ItemGroup` and I want to group them by their second property. So I wrote something like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="groupStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Expander IsExpanded="False" Header="{Binding Name}">
                            <ItemsPresenter />
                        </Expander>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ListView x:Name="lv">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
        <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource groupStyle}"/>
        </ListView.GroupStyle>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

and in the code behind

```
// here, list is the collection of items with mentioned properties.
lv.ItemsSource = list;
var view = (CollectionView) CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lv.ItemsSource);
if (view.GroupDescriptions != null)
{
    view.GroupDescriptions.Clear();
    view.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("ItemGroup"));
}
```

Now everything works smoothly. But the problem is, sometimes I want to expand all the `Expander`s in code behind, and I found no way to access them and set their `IsExpanded` property to true. How can I do this?

*Edit*: here is the method I use to find the Expanders, e.g. `FindChildren<Expander>(lv)` But it always return an empty collection

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindChildren<T>(DependencyObject obj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (obj == null)
    {
        yield break;
    }
    int vt_count = obj is Visual ? VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj) : 0;
    var children = vt_count > 0
        ? Enumerable.Range(0, vt_count).Select(n => VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, n))
        : LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(obj).OfType<DependencyObject>();

    foreach (var child in children)
    {
        if (child is T)
        {
            yield return (T) child;
            continue;
        }
        foreach (T descendant in FindChildren<T>(child))
            yield return descendant;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Weirdly*, the answer posted by @mm8 didn't work and I couldn't figure out why. But anyway I managed to do a workaround. The key is to bind the `IsExpanded` property of the expander to an unused property of the `ListView`, e.g. its tag:

```
<ControlTemplate>
    <Expander Header="{Binding Name}">
        <Expander.IsExpanded>
            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}" Path="Tag" />
        </Expander.IsExpanded>
        <ItemsPresenter />
    </Expander>
</ControlTemplate>
```

and then you can control the `IsExpanded` property of all of them by setting `lv.Tag = true;` or `lv.Tag = false;` in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the `Expander` elements in the visual tree using a recursive method and the `VisualTreeHelper` class:

```
private void ExpandButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Expander gi in FindVisualChildren<Expander>(lv))
    {
        gi.IsExpanded = true;
    }
}

private static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
            if (child != null && child is T)
            {
                yield return (T)child;
            }

            foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
            {
                yield return childOfChild;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** If you want to do this as soon as you have set the `ItemsSource` property of the `ListView`, you need to wait until the containers have been created. Handle the `Loaded` event:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // here, list is the collection of items with mentioned properties.
    lv.ItemsSource = list;
    var view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lv.ItemsSource);
    if (view.GroupDescriptions != null)
    {
        view.GroupDescriptions.Clear();
        view.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("ItemGroup"));
    }

    Loaded += (s, e) =>
    {
        foreach (Expander gi in FindVisualChildren<Expander>(lv))
        {
            gi.IsExpanded = true;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: This code works well. @polfosol did you call the code from a event listener or did you append it afer `view.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("ItemGroup"));`?

Comment: The markup is a brief, minimal version of my code. But I am pretty certain that it's not working. My project is based on .net 4 client, and I am using win 7 with vs2013

Comment: Did you event bother to try this solution along with the sample code you have provided? Or how can you be "certain" that something that obviously works is "not working"?

Comment: When I call `FindVisualChildren<Expander>(lv))` from the constructor, its in fact not working and `VisualTreeHelper` returns an empty collection.

Comment: Who says you should call it from the constructor? By then there are no containers created. My sample uses an event handler.

Comment: See my edit for an example of how to expand the expanders once the containers have actually been created.

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong. It's impossible for anyone to point out what given the lack of information in your question.

Comment: Just to second this: All this example code provided by @mm8 works in my example solution.

Comment: Where, how and when do you call the FindChildren method?

Comment: Sorry if this is getting annoying. When the ListView is populated/loaded, I call the method by pressing a button. I am getting suspicious that this is an issue with my .net version. Have you tried this with .net 4 client?

Comment: "When the ListView is populated/loaded"? You need to wait until after the contains have been loaded...did you see my edit? You can't set the ItemsSource and then call FindChildren in the same method.

Comment: did you create a brand new wpf project with your code and tested it? Perhaps some other code in your project is messing with the listview?

Comment: I said _by pressing a button_ which means I am seeing the ListView with all the items already. Pressing the button is just for expanding the Expanders. And sorry if I am not available in the next 2 hours. I need to go somewhere now.